# How to save to online database from string results of custom dialog in android

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have a program that gets string from a custom dialog box to a listview in an activity and I want the strings I got to be saved to database the same time they are being passed to the textviews

Code:

```
public class orderlist extends AppCompatActivity {
        List<String> qty = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> qtytype = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> products = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> store = new ArrayList<>();

        ListView orderlist;
        FloatingActionButton btnOrder;
        MydAdapter adapter;

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(orderlist.this, Main2Activity.class);
            orderlist.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }

    String saveProduct, saveQty, saveStore, saveQtyType;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_orderpage);
            orderlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.orderlistview);
            btnOrder = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.order);

            String saveProduct, saveQty, saveStore, saveQtyType;

            btnOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(orderlist.this);
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) orderlist.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null, false);
                    builder.setView(view);
                    builder.setCancelable(false);
                    RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();

                    final EditText txtproductname, txtstore, txtquantity;
                    final Spinner txtqtytype;
                    txtproductname = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.TxtProductName);
                    txtstore = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.TxtStoreName);
                    txtquantity = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.TxtQuantity);

                    List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    arrayList.add("pieces");
                    arrayList.add("pesos");
                    arrayList.add("kilos");
                    arrayList.add("ml");
                    arrayList.add("grams");
                    arrayList.add("bundle");
                    ArrayAdapter<String> spinneradapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(orderlist.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);

                    spinneradapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    txtqtytype = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerQuantityType);
                    txtqtytype.setAdapter(spinneradapter);
                    txtqtytype.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            String value = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                            //Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView <?> parent) {
                        }
                    });

                    builder.setPositiveButton("Proceed", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            qty.add(txtquantity.getText().toString());
                            qtytype.add(txtqtytype.getSelectedItem().toString());
                            products.add(txtproductname.getText().toString());
                            store.add(txtstore.getText().toString());

                            Toast.makeText(orderlist.this, txtproductname.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            adapter = new MydAdapter(orderlist.this, qty, qtytype, products, store);
                            orderlist.setAdapter(adapter);

                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.create().show();
                }
            });
        }

    class MydAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
            List<String> adapter_products;
            List<String> adapter_qty;
            List<String> adapter_store;
            List<String> adapter_qtytype;
            public MydAdapter(Context context, List<String> qty, List<String> qtytype, List<String> products, List<String> store) {
                super(context, R.layout.activity_orderlist, R.id.quantity, qty);
                this.adapter_qty = qty;
                this.adapter_qtytype = qtytype;
                this.adapter_products = products;
                this.adapter_store = store;
            }
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                //Inflating layout
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                @SuppressLint("ViewHolder") View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_orderlist, parent, false);
                TextView txtProduct, txtQty, txtStore, txtQtyType;
                Button btnCancel;
                txtProduct = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.productname);
                txtQty = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
                txtStore = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.storename);
                txtQtyType = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.quantitytype);
                btnCancel = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

                txtQty.setText(adapter_qty.get(position));
                txtQtyType.setText(adapter_qtytype.get(position));
                txtProduct.setText(adapter_products.get(position));
                txtStore.setText(adapter_store.get(position));

                btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        qty.remove(position);
                        qtytype.remove(position);
                        products.remove(position);
                        store.remove(position);

                        adapter= new MydAdapter(orderlist.this, qty, qtytype, products, store);
                        orderlist.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });
                return row;
            }
        }
    }
```

So this is where I need to get the data from. I've tried using Async but I cant seem to get it working

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Proceed", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            qty.add(txtquantity.getText().toString());
                            qtytype.add(txtqtytype.getSelectedItem().toString());
                            products.add(txtproductname.getText().toString());
                            store.add(txtstore.getText().toString());

                            Toast.makeText(orderlist.this, txtproductname.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            adapter = new MydAdapter(orderlist.this, qty, qtytype, products, store);
                            orderlist.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Do you guys know a method how i can do this?

Comment: How this is related to PHP at all?

Comment: I'm missing what the problem is a little bit, or it is too broad. Since you have a place where you update your textviews, this could be the place where you save it in your database as well? You can use Room for easy access to your internal SQLite DB.